# Error converting [data type] nvarchar to integer

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have an application which will allow the user to insert their details. but I am getting an error. I have already tried the solutions that are available on StackOverflow or any other blog.

### here is the c# code.

```
if (Page.IsValid)
    {

        string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spRegisterUser", con)
            {
                CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            };

            SqlParameter username = new SqlParameter("@UserName", txtUserName.Text);

            string encryptedPassword = FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile(txtPassword.Text, "SHA1");
            SqlParameter password = new SqlParameter("@Password", encryptedPassword);
            SqlParameter email = new SqlParameter("@Email", txtEmail.Text);
            SqlParameter mobileno = new SqlParameter("@MobileNo", txtMobileNo.Text);

            cmd.Parameters.Add(username);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(password);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(email);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(mobileno);
            con.Open();

            int ReturnCode = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            if (ReturnCode == -1)
            {
                lblMessage.Text = "User Name already in use, please choose another user name";
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("Login Successfully");
                //Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Here is the Stored Procedure

```
create proc spRegisterUser  
@UserName nvarchar(100),  
@Password nvarchar(200),  
@Email nvarchar(200),  
@MobileNo int

 declare @count int  
 declare @returncode int  

 --declare @count1 int  
 --declare @returncode1 int  

 select @count = count(username)  
 from tblUser where UserName=@UserName  
 if @count>0  
 begin   
 set @returncode = -1  
 end  
 else  
 begin   
 set @returncode=1  

 insert into tblUser values(@UserName,@Password,@Email,@MobileNo)  
 End  
 select @returncode as ReturnValue  
 End
```

### This is the Stack Trace

```
     [SqlException (0x80131904): Error converting data type nvarchar to int.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +2551578
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +5951128
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +285
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) +4169
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData() +58
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData() +89
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption, Boolean shouldCacheForAlwaysEncrypted) +430
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest) +2598
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry) +1483
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method) +64
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar() +271
   Project.WebForm2.btnSubmit_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in E:\Visual Studio 2012\Project\Project\Registration\SignUp.aspx.cs:54
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +9782378
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +204
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +12
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +15
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +35
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1639
```

**Please Provide Solution as soon as possible**

Comment: Is this Stored Procedure correct? This line is quite strange to me: @MobileNo inProcedurebegin

Comment: That is Int Bytheway

Comment: Error message says it all.. you are trying to insert 'nvarchar' into database variable type `int`. My best guess it is `@MobileNo` parameter. Debug your code and see what  value comes in `txtMobileNo.Text` field.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is being caused by passing values to `@MobileNo` parameter which you have declared as integer in stored procedure.
You need to have validation in code behind before passing value from `txtMobileNo.Text` to `@MobileNo` parameter which validates that value entered in textbox is valid integer.

See [**Int32.TryParse**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx) method to validate text is valid integer.

Otherwise declare @MobileNo parameter in stored proc to V**A**RCHAR eg

```
create proc spRegisterUser  
@UserName nvarchar(100),  
@Password nvarchar(200),  
@Email nvarchar(200),  
@MobileNo VARCHAR(15)

--Rest of code
```

Comment: Thankyou Mudassir Hasan. It's Working Now.

Comment: One More Thing I want to know. how can I stop email duplicacy to store in Database? just like i use in username

Comment: With a constraint. And please accept the response as an answer. You're not new and should know how SO is designed to work. People search for answers here and these cannot be found if you don't do your part.